# Dragging and dropping control onto windows form designer does nothing

Tags: c#, controls, visual-c#-express-2010

Whenever I try to drag and drop a custom made control onto the visual form designer, it does not load and is not added to the form (even highlighting over the control area does not say that it is there). However when I drag other custom made controls (Ones that I have made), they show up perfectly onto the form/visual designer. I am using Visual C# 2010 and my custom control is a class set up like the following:

```
class MyControl : UserControl
{
    //...
}
```

I have also tried changing `UserControl` to `Control` but nothing happens, it still does not show up. I can take some screenshots if it may help.

Comment: Why the downvote? Should the question include more information because I am not sure what else to put. It is an actual problem that I am having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the control was in a different namespace than the one that the visual designer was using. All I had to do was change the namespace of my control back to what it was and it worked.